# Start and Stop time in javascript + angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time

I am building employee work tracking application, I have one start and stop button in UI.

My jade code:

```
td.table-icon-cell
    a.btn.btn-primary(type='button' href='',ng-click='stop();' ng-if="start.active")
      i.fa.fa-stop(aria-hidden='true') &nbsp; Stop 
    a.btn.btn-primary(type='button' href='',ng-click='start();' ng-if="!start.active")
       i.fa.fa-clock-o(aria-hidden='true') &nbsp; Start
```

controllers.js:

```
$scope.start = function () {
    $scope.time = {
        start : moment(new Date()),
        stop : ''
    }
    $scope.start.active = true;
    $http.post('/api/timestart', $scope.time).then(function (response) {
            $scope.savetimes = response.data;
        });
}

$scope.stop = function () {
    $scope.start.active = false;
    $scope.time = {
        start: '',
        stop: moment(new Date())
    }
    $http.post('/api/timestop', $scope.time).then(function (response) {});
}
```

For example:

I am a employee i press the Start button, then it becomes as "Stop" button its good, but if i load my page i want "Stop" button again, but it displaying "Start" from first.

Comment: what is the default value for `$scope.start.active`? (do you initialise it in your controller?)

Comment: Yes see my code: i have two modes, $scope.start.active = true and false.

Comment: they are only set IF you call either of those functions: start(), stop(). When you _load_ your pages, does any of the functions fire? Otherwise `$scope.start.active` will be undefined

Comment: Yes how to write stuff? if user once click start i want to make stop button looks in UI, even if page loads still the user again needs to press stop.

Comment: in your controller, try to initialise `$scope.start.active = false;` outside of any functions

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can you post some piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be **two** issues.

Firstly, you need to **initialise** your variable. You can just write `$scope.start.active = false;` within your controller. For example:

```
app.controller('your_controller', function($scope, $http) {
  ...
  $scope.start.active = false;
  ...
  $scope.start = function () {...}
  $scope.stop = function () {...}
});
```

This way, when you reload a page, it will always have your value as `false`. (Or you can set it as `true` if you want)

---

Secondly, I believe you have a **bug**. Your **function** `start()` has the same name as your **variable** `start` (or `$scope.start`). This may break your `ng-if` logic. For example:

```js
start = function(){}
console.log(!start.anything);
```

In this example (if you run it) you will see that if you treat a function as an object with some properties, it will return `true` because `!` of `undefined` is true.

So in your example `ng-if="!start.active"` evaluates to true and so it displays **"Start"**.

To fix it, you just need to **rename** your variables so that they will no longer match each other.